# Переписать код С++ на php

Tags: ассемблер, c++, php

Есть такой код на С++
Как написать аналог на php?  
Собственно с командами ассемблера проблема:

```
__asm mov eax,x;  
__asm sar eax,0x10;  
__asm mov x,eax;
```

Вот весь код:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int key = 0xECD6D157;
unsigned short GetNumber() {
    unsigned long x,y;
    x = key;
    y = x + x * 2;
    y = x + y * 4;
    y = y * 0x10;
    y += x;
    y = y * 0x100;
    y -= x;
    x = x + y * 4 + 0x269EC3;
    key = x;
    __asm mov eax,x;
    __asm sar eax,0x10;
    __asm mov x,eax;
    return x & 0x7fff;
}
int main(int argc,char *argv[]) {
    short num;
    char c;
    FILE *f1 = fopen(argv[1],"rb");
    FILE *f2 = fopen(argv[2],"wb");
    while (!feof(f1)) {
        c = fgetc(f1);
        num = GetNumber();
        c ^= num;
        fputc(c,f2);
    }
}
```

Спасибо.
P.S. Это уже абсолютно весь код проги на С++
В общем ничего этакого в нем нет и кому надо и так могли бы нагуглить код.

Вот попытка переписать на php

```
     class MyTest
     {
        protected $key=0xECD6D157;
        protected $eax;

        function GetNumber() 
        {
            // unsigned long x,y;
            // var_dump($this->key);
            $x = $this->key;
            $y = $x + $x * 2;
            $y = $x + $y * 4;
            $y = $y * 0x10;
            $y += $x;
            $y = $y * 0x100;
            $y -= $x;
            $x = $x + $y * 4 + 0x269EC3;
            $this->key = ($x);

            $this->eax = ($x >> 0x10);
            $x = $this->eax;

            return ($x & 0x7fff);
        }

        function crypt($argv1,$argv2) {
            // short num;
             // char c;
            $num;
            $c;
            $f1 = fopen($argv1,"rb");
            $f2 = fopen($argv2,"wb");
            while (!feof($f1)) 
            {
                $cs = fgetc($f1);
                $c=ord($cs);    //букву в число             
                $num = $this->GetNumber();
                $c ^= $num;
                fputs($f2, pack('c', $c));  
            }
            fclose($f2);
            fclose($f1);

            echo file_get_contents($argv2);
        }
     }
     $f_name1="tmp.ms";
     $f_name2="tmp.mse";

     $testCrypt = new MyTest();
     $testCrypt->crypt($f_name1,$f_name2);
```

Comment: Очень похоже на уже  немного обработанный вручную код из декомпайлера...

Comment: @avp: так и есть, никто в здравом уме не будет расписывать умножение на 49 таким образом.

Comment: @mikillskegg: вы правы, погорячился.

Comment: @Track, а в чем собственно проблема? 

К сожалению я не знаток PHP, а на Си дело происходить так (кстати, @VladD в своем ответе аривел "человеческую" формулу для изменения `key`).

При каждом запуске программы **32-бит** key устанавливается в 0xECD6D157. Для каждого прочитанного из файла байта он перевычисляется. Все вычисления происходят с **беззнакавыми 32-бит целыми** (возможно, что в ПХП не работает именно этот аспект). 

Далее из нового значения key возвращаются 16 бит, начиная с 10-го, а на самом деле в XOR с прочитанным байтом участвуют младшие 8 бит из них.

--

Что у Вас не работает?

Comment: @Track, @avp: да, в PHP [нету беззнакового целого](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.integer.php). Для C/C++ это было бы не страшно, так как результат умножения всё равно считается по модулю `2^32`, и набор бит не зависит от знака, но в PHP при переполнении результат преобразуется во `float`. Причём это поведение зависит от того, 32- или 64-битная ли у нас система.

Comment: Да - так и есть - выдает вот такую чушь.    
Похоже придется придумывать что-то другое

    float(3973501271) 
    float(8.5038093004153E+14) 
    float(1.8199257398098E+20) 
    float(3.8948776735392E+25) 
    float(8.3355445554714E+30) 
    float(1.7839148969501E+36) 
    float(3.8178097884098E+41) 
    float(INF) 
    float(NAN)

Comment: @Track: Проще всего перейти на 64-битную систему. Для 32-битной системы можно попробовать перемножать отдельно верхнюю и нижнюю половину переменной. Что-то наподобие такого: https://ideone.com/LvR6cr

Заметьте, что я поменял начальное значение `$key` на такое же в битовом выражении, т.к. там был сразу float из-за переполнения.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Давайте сначала перепишем на чистый C++:

```
__asm mov eax,x;
__asm sar eax,0x10;
__asm mov x,eax;
```

Это копирует переменную `x` в регистр `eax`, сдвигает значение на `0x10` бит вправо, и копирует результат назад.

То же самое можно записать так:

```
x >>= 0x10;
```

Эта команда, как мы видим, убирает младшие 16 бит у `x`. Ваш код скорее всего работает с 32-битным `unsigned long`, это оставляет *старшие* 16 бит, то есть старшее слово из `x`. Выражение `x & 0x7fff` убирает *старший* бит результата.

Таким образом, биты, помеченные буквой `R`, переезжают, как показано внизу:

```
*RRRRRRR RRRRRRRR ******** ********  -->
00000000 00000000 0RRRRRRR RRRRRRRR
```

Стало яснее?

На PHP тоже есть битовые операции, так что вы можете этот кусок кода переписать так:

```
$x = $x >> 16;
return $x & 0x7fff;
```

---

Кстати, весь код на C++ можно упростить:

```
unsigned int key = 0xECD6D12;
unsigned short GetNumber() {
    key = 49 * key + 0x269EC3;
    return (key >> 0x10) & 0x7fff;
}
```

Оптимизацию лучше оставить оптимизатору, а не разворачивать вручную.

---

PS: как справедливо заметил наш злой собеседник, `sar` означает сдвиг знакового, а не беззнакового числа. В нашем случае это, однако, не играет никакой роли, т.к. знаковый бит маскируется последующим `& 0x7fff`.

Comment: Спасибо, но похоже еще в чем-то проблема.  
Можем лично пообщаться?  
Скину весь код.  
Разумеется за вознаграждение.  
alex_3d-kstudio.com

Comment: @Track: Извините, на общение вне сайта времени сейчас нет. Спрашивайте здесь, поможем.

Comment: @Track: если ваш код на PHP, возможно, инициализация `key` происходит при _каждом_ запросе. Вам надо хранить значение `key` в сессии или где-то ещё.

Comment: @mikillskegg возможны другие варианты:

    -- Ты знаешь, кто это?
    -- Кто?
    -- Это Неуловимый Джо! Вот уже 20 лет он скачет про прериям...